# Error al compilar un programa de una tienda de productos

Tags: dev-c++

En las librerías me da este error

> O:\programas  c++\productos.cpp    In function 'int main()':

Y en la linea 9 este error

> O:\programas c++\productos.cpp [Error] expected initializer before 'cout'

El programa es como un menú de productos en el que tu eliges la opción y la imprime en pantalla:

```
#include "iostream"/* linea de error*/
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int tienda
    
    cout<<"/t/t/tienda/n";/* línea del error*/
    int t_ventas, t_cliente, producto, i , arr , suma , t_tienda;
    float precio_prod;
    char cliente, t_producto;
    
    cout<<"deseas ingresar como cliente"<<endl;
    cin>>cliente;
    while(cliente=='s')
    
    
    {
        
        t_cliente=0;
        cout<<"deseas ingresar un producto"<<endl;
        cin>>t_producto;
        while(t_producto== 's')
        
        {
            
            {
                cout<<"1.frijoles 119"<<endl;
                cout<<"2.arroz 115"<<endl;
                cout<<"3.cebolla 15"<<endl;
                cout<<"4.salsina 18"<<endl;
                cout<<"5.espagueti 110"<<endl;
                cout<<"elige la opcion del producto"<<endl;
                cin>>t_producto;
                {
                    arr=t_tienda;
                }
                t_tienda;
                cout<<"desea ingresar otro producto"<<endl;
                cin>>t_producto;
            }
             
                cout<<"total"<<t_cliente<<endl;
                t_ventas=t_cliente=t_ventas;
                cout<<"desea ingresar de otra vez como cliente"<<endl;
                cin>>t_cliente;
                
        }
        cout<<"corte"<<t_ventas<<endl;
        getch();
    }
}
```

Este es el link del video que estaba viendo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DCJpP4wYh4

Comment: Te falta un `;` en la línea donde declaras la variable tienda. `int tienda` debería ser `int tienda;`.

Comment: Bienvenido. No son 2 errores por separado. La primera línea te está informando en qué función de qué archivo se encuentra el error.

Answer (score 0):

Además de faltar `;` en la variable:

```
int tienda
```

Falta el `return 0` al final del código; esta instrucción `return 0`, con el valor **cero**, indica que el programa ha finalizado con éxito, lo cual se considera una buena práctica al utilizar el lenguaje.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  
  return 0;
}
```

El mensaje de error `O:\programas c++\productos.cpp [Error] expected initializer before 'cout'` aparece en la línea que comentó porque está intentando imprimir una string que no está permitida en **C++**, `/t/t/tienda/n`, caracteres que no están permitidos en **C++**, que es `/t`.

El operador de `\t` tabulación en una string no es considerado válido en **C++**. Esto se debe a que es un operador del procesador y no de lenguaje **C++**, y no está listado en la [*sección oficial del lenguaje*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Sin embargo, en el lenguaje [**C**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape) es válido.

La forma correcta de tu código debería seguir este modelo.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "stdio.h"
 #include "conio.h"
 using namespace std;
    
  int main() {

    int tienda;
   
    
    cout <<"tienda/n";   /* Línea corregida.*/
   //Todo el código complementario...
      
      return 0;
    }
```